# MFC dialog freezes when it looses focus

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mfc

I am new to MFC so please bear with me. I have a Dialog that is displayed in full screen on a dual screen monitor. This dialog is instantiated inside another non-modal dialog (when a button is clicked). Something like:

```
void MyCParentDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
        dlg2 = new MyChildNonModalDlg();
        dlg2->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

In the `OnInitDialog()` of `MyChildNonModalDlg`, `ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE)` is invoked to make it the dialog full-screen with no-border. Now, there is a button callback event inside `MyChildNonModalDlg`:

```
void MyChildNonModalDlg::onBnClickedBut2() {
    // Display images on the dialog one by one for a very long time 
}
```

While `onBnClickedBut2` is running and the dialog is being updated continuously, if I click with my mouse outside the dialog (say on the other screen) meaning when the dialog **looses focus**, it freezes!

I know this is something perhaps that can be fixed with multi-threading, where the process inside `OnBnClickedBut2()` must run inside a thread, but as someone who knows very little about thread, can someone point me to the right direction or provide code examples that can do this?

Comment: Note, same problem happens when child dialog is **not** full-screen, so this issue is not due to it being in full-screen mode.

Comment: It freezes because Windows puts up the "not responding" ghost window.  This is just not valid in UI code, you *must* run long loops on another thread.

Comment: OK I think I have figured this one out, here is an excellent introduction to threading in MFC, downloading the example code and studying it actually helped me learn within an hour how to do multi-threading and this too with very little thread background. Link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5542/Simple-Multithreaded-Application-in-pure-C-Win32-a

Answer (score 0):

Use `AfxBeginThread` to create new thread inside `onBnClickedBut2`. You are not supposed to block UI event handlers. Hope you got it by now.